# Construct a signal that is multiplied by a white noise?

Tags: reconstruction, noise-cancellation

Can we reconstructs a signal after it is being multiplied (not added) by a random noise (not with the normal distribution)?

Lets say I have S=10*sin(2*pi*5*t) for t=[0:.001:1] and I have a random noise V for the same time t. How Can I reconstruct S from X=S.*V (element wise product)?

Is is theoretically possible? I read this [post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13895/which-domain-used-for-denoising-additive-and-multiplicative-noises) about the Multiplicative noise but still I need help.

If the noise is truly random, doesn't mean that it can ruin the signal completely?

Thanks,

Background of my question: there is a machine learning method called "Non-negative matrix factorization" that can be used to find the components of a signal (assume signal is a combination of those components). I have seen this method as able to find the right components even after the combined signal was multiplied by a white noise!!

Comment: It is impossible to obtain $S$ from $X$. Even if you know $V$ perfectly, it could equal zero, and then $S$ would be indeterminate. It may still be possible to tell something about the signal (such as its "components", whatever that is), but not its precise value.

Comment: @MBaz the same is true for additive noise

Comment: Can we assume the signal is Sine Wave?

Comment: @MarcusMüller That is true, but that wasn't the question :-P

Comment: @Royi If you know an answer for a set of restricted signals, I would be interested in reading it.

Comment: @MBaz, I didn't state I have a solution as perfect reconstruction isn't achievable. I'm just asking if it can be specific so I will try thinking about some approach. Not necessarily good or something. Just something to think of.

Comment: @MBaz I can offer you a formula for the density of the product of two independent RVs; ACF would be but another step from there. Should I consider that an answer to this question and post as such?

Comment: [Non negative matrix factorisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization) is not a machine learning method. Such factorisations pop up every where. It **is** used in machine learning for sure but it is not a machine learning method. Rant over. If you leave the question open as it is then no, you cannot reconstruct, but, in [some cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct-sequence_spread_spectrum) you can (still this might be not what you are after though :/ ).

Comment: @Royi I understand, and my comment didn't have any ulterior motives; I'd be honestly interested to see what is the best that can be achieved in this case, even if only for a restricted set of functions. For instance, if you know there is a pure sine wave under zero-mean noise, it may be possible to take a large number of samples and average them somehow, to cancel the noise, and then infer the signal's frequency, amplitude and phase.

Comment: @MarcusMüller What is ACF? BTW, I would consider any progress towards a solution to be a good answer to this question.